# M2.1.9 - How to display total ordered qty on email template?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to display the total ordered qty on email template. I can implement this function on Magento-1 using the following code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
/**
 * @var $this Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals
 * @see Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals
 */
?>


    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" ><strong>Total Qty</strong></td>
        <td class="last" style="width:300px;">
        <strong>
        <?php $_order = $this->getOrder(); //call the order
               $order_qty = floor($_order->getData('total_qty_ordered')); //get qty of all items rounded to full number (without 3.0000 or so)
            echo $order_qty;?>
            ( 

             <?if($order_qty >= 12){?> 

                <?$mods = intval($order_qty)%12;?>
                <?php $dzn = explode('.' ,intval($order_qty)/12); ?> <?echo $dzn[0]?> Dozen <?printf("%d", $mods);?>  Pcs 
                <?}else{?>
                <?echo ($order_qty*1)/12 ;?>
                <?}?>
                )
        </strong>
        </td>



    </tr>
```

[image]

But I was trying to use `$_order->getData('total_qty_ordered')` under `/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/total.pthml`(This is original path, I already overwrote it under my custom template folder) but it doesn't work. How can I do this.

Thank you

Comment: In Magento 2, what is the template you used?

Comment: Luma template!!

Comment: Can you give me the full path of this file?

Comment: /public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/total.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the class: [\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php)

As we can see, we can get the order: `$order = $block->getOrder();`

Comment: You mean that i need to use `$block->getOrder()->getData('total_qty_orderer') ` instead of `this->getOrder()->getData('total_qty_ordered')`?

Comment: You can use `$this` also.